# dictionary of folders and subfolders

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to make function, which will return for a given folder, a Dictionary, which describes its content. Keys let be the names of the subfolders and files, key value representing the file should be their size and key values ​​that represent folders, whether they are dictionaries that describe the content of these subfolders. The order is not important. Here is an example of such a dictionary:

```
{
   'delo' : {
      'navodila.docx' : 83273,
      'poročilo.pdf' : 37653347,
      'artikli.dat' : 253
   },
   'igre' : {},
   'seznam.txt' : 7632,
   'razno' : {
      'slika.jpg' : 4275,
      'prijatelji' : {
         'janez.jpg' : 8734765,
         'mojca.png' : 8736,
         'veronika.jpg' : 8376535,
         'miha.gif' : 73645
      },
      'avto.xlsx' : 76357
   }
   'ocene.xlsx' : 8304
}
```

i have made this till now :

```
import os

def izpis(map):
    slovar={}
    listFiles = os.listdir(map)
    for ts in listFiles:
        fullName = map +'\\' + ts

        if os.path.isfile(fullName):
            size=os.path.getsize(fullName)
            slovar[ts]=size
        else:
            slovar+=izpis(fullName)





    return (slovar)
```

Comment: ... And your question is ?

Comment: I'd take a look at `os.walk`...

Comment: my question is how to put every file in newline and how to continoue with that else. I want to try with recursion but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def f(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d = {}
        for name in os.listdir(path):
            d[name] = f(os.path.join(path, name))
    else:
        d = os.path.getsize(path)
    return d
```

Comment: thank you very much. But how tu put evry file in newline like in example

Comment: @user2471076, import pprint; pprint.pprint(f('.')) is one way.

Comment: @user2471076, import json; print json.dumps(f('.'), indent=4) is another.

Comment: is there any other way like('\n') ? because we havent taken pprint in school yet

Answer (score 1):

```
def dumps(d, level=0, indent=4):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if not d: return '{}'
        return '{\n' + ',\n'.join(
            (' ' * (level+indent) + "'{}' : {}".format(name, dumps(d[name], level+indent, indent)) for name in d),
        ) + '\n' + ' ' * level + '}'
    else:
        return str(d)

print dumps({
   'delo' : {
      'navodila.docx' : 83273,
      'porocilo.pdf' : 37653347,
      'artikli.dat' : 253
   },
   'igre' : {},
   'seznam.txt' : 7632,
   'razno' : {
      'slika.jpg' : 4275,
      'prijatelji' : {
         'janez.jpg' : 8734765,
         'mojca.png' : 8736,
         'veronika.jpg' : 8376535,
         'miha.gif' : 73645
      },
      'avto.xlsx' : 76357
   },
   'ocene.xlsx' : 8304
})
```

Comment: and  now i have to make function, that will write out dictionary clearly from former task. i have to use nested readout(i think its called "nested") with suitable deviations from left edge

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: you have seen it what I meant

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def get_listings(directory):
    parent, folder = os.path.split(directory)
    listings = {
        'folder': folder,
        'children-files': [],
        'children-folders': [],
    }

    children = os.listdir(directory)
    for child in children:
        child_path = os.path.join(directory, child)
        if os.path.isdir(child_path):
            listings['children-folders'] += [get_listings( child_path )]
        else:
            listings['children-files'] += [child]


    return listings




directory = '/home/user/hello'   
print(get_listings(directory))
```

output is:

```
{
    'folder': 'hello',
    'children-files': ['a2', '1'],
    'children-folders': [{
        'folder': '002',
        'children-files': [],
        'children-folders': []
    }, {
        'folder': '001',
        'children-files': ['1'],
        'children-folders': [{
            'folder': 'aaaa',
            'children-files': ['321'],
            'children-folders': []
        }]
    }]
}
```