# How to dict folders?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have to make a function to transform example 1 into example 2. I have already made a function for example 1. How do I make a function for example 2, with nested readout and with their sizes in brackets and with newlines?

example 1.

```
{
       'delo' : {
          'navodila.docx' : 83273,
          'poročilo.pdf' : 37653347,
        },
       'igre' : {},
       'seznam.txt' : 7632,
       'razno' : {
          'slika.jpg' : 4275,
          'prijatelji' : {
             'janez.jpg' : 8734765,
   }
```

example 2.

```
delo 
   navodila.docx (83273)
   poročilo.pdf (37653347)
   artikli.dat (253)
igre
seznam.txt (7632)
razno
   slika.jpg (4275)
   prijatelji
      janez.jpg (8734765)
```

My function I've made already for the first example, except without newlines:

```
import os

def f(folder):
    dict={}
    list = os.listdir(folder)
    for ts in list:
        fullName = folder + '\\' + ts

        if os.path.isfile(fullName):
            size=os.path.getsize(fullname)
            dict[ts]=size
        else:
            dict[ts]=f(fullName)
        return (dict)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to print the dict in example 1 so that the output looks like example 2?

Comment: @Lanaru i think something like this yes ...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17025300/2225682

Comment: This is the third question of this sort I've seen this week!  Must be homework.

Comment: @falsetru it's related because it's the same user that asked it.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable. You override the dictionary constructor...

Comment: sorry really , actually it is homework but I would be really pleased if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i really wanted, an easier way , just to refill it

```
def f(map,n=0): 
        dictionary=beforeF(map) #function before i made
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            fullName = map + '\\' + key
            if path.isdir(fullName): 
                print(n*'\t'+key+':')

                f(fullName, n+1)
            else:
                print(n*'\t'+key + ' (' + str(dictionary[key])+ ')')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def dump(d, level=0, indent=4):
    for name in d:
        if isinstance(d[name], dict):
            print('{0}{1}'.format(' ' * level, name))
            dump(d[name], level+indent)
        else:
            print('{0}{1} ({2})'.format(' ' * level, name, d[name]))
```

Comment: but what is this "d"?

Comment: Dictionary returned from f(). Use dump as: dump(f('.'))

Comment: i doesnt work, it returns "ValueError: zero length field name in format"... but i believe that there is an easier way

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve the problem. The main idea is the same, expect that you have to print the structure recursively, remembering the indent and passing it on as you call the function.

Your first version of code needs a small correction, the indent at the return statement is one tab too large. Also, only an advice, list and dict are poor choice for variable names, as they are already built in types.

```
import os

def f(folder):
    mape={}
    sez = os.listdir(folder)
    for ts in sez:
#        if ts == "." or ts == "..": continue
        fullName = folder + '/' + ts
        if os.path.isfile(fullName):
            size=os.path.getsize(fullName)
            mape[ts]=size
        else:
            mape[ts]=f(fullName)
    return (mape)

struktura = f('.')

def output(tree, zam=0):
    for i in tree:
        if isinstance(tree[i], (int, long)):
            print "{0}{1} ({2})".format(' '*zam*4, i, tree[i])
        else:
            print ' '*zam*4+i
            output(tree[i],zam+1)

output(struktura)
```

Naturally, the output function does the printing as you wanted.
I hope this helps and solves your problem.

PS: Kakšne čudne domače naloge mate to?...

Comment: Ne dela, ne vem zakaj , piše value error 
ma nwm niti sam kaksne so to domace naloge

Comment: Ja, ta value error je verjetno zarad python verzije. Ostevilct mors  {} v print stavku, v pythonu 2.7 in naprej pa jih ni treba. Torej:  '{}{} ({})' spremen v '{0}{1} ({2})' pa bo delal. In ne, ne da se bl enostavno...